# Which tense matches the phrase "throughout the time"?

Tags: tense

Which tense matches the phrase "throughout the time":

> Throughout the time, I have been working.
>
> I have worked throughout the time.
>
> I worked throughout the time.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: 'Throughout the time' is a deictic expression, and needs specification. 'Conduct yourselves with fear throughout the time of your [now/future] exile.' / 'I struggled with ill health throughout the time of my youth.'

Answer (score 2):

**Throughout the time, I have been working.**

This really doesn't work. It is like Yoda talking. "Afraid he is" instead of "He is afraid."

**I have worked throughout the time.**

This works, but the implication of "have worked" is that the time is in the immediate past. Like the shift you just worked.

**I worked throughout the time.**

This works, but the implication of "worked" is that the time is in the distant past. Like the shift you worked last week.

---

As a native English speaker (well American English, not real English) a final note. "Throughout the time" is really an odd phrase. I'd say that "I worked the whole time", or something like that, meaning that I really worked and didn't goof off playing computer games.